# NameError: when instantiating a class in kv via a python statement in an event callback (e.g. on_parent)

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, nameerror

I get the error "NameError: name 'MyButton' is not defined" when I try to make an instance of MyButton class directly. As a workaround, I extend this class in root widget (see MuButton2) and then there is no problem. Can someone explain why this is the case?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from itertools import cycle

Builder.load_string('''

<MyButton>:

<MainWidget>:
    
    BoxLayout:

        on_parent:
            for i in range(2,4): self.add_widget(root.MyButton2(text = str(i), pos=self.pos))    
            #for i in range(1,3): self.add_widget(MyButton(text = str(i), pos=self.pos)) #<-- results in NameError: name 'MyButton' is not defined   

        MyButton: #<-- however this works fine
            text: '1'
''')

class MyButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Button, self).__init__(**kwargs)    
        self.colours=cycle([(1,0,0,1),(0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,1)])
        
    def on_press(self):
        self.background_color=next(self.colours)

        
class MainWidget(BoxLayout):

    class MyButton2(MyButton):
        pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that problem by using `kivy.factory.Factory`. Add to the beginning of your `kv` string:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
```

And then, use it as:

```
for i in range(1,3): self.add_widget(Factory.MyButton(text = str(i), pos=self.pos))
```

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed fix it so I have accepted the answer, though I am still curious why it does not just work without Factory. Something about the order in which things are initialised perhaps?